# Role Based Authorization on Azure App Service not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am in the middle of deploying a legacy application to azure that is running on .net 4.6.2 (MVC/EF). I am having an issue with role-based security. I can run this application no problem locally targeting the azure database as well as within IIS on a physical device. When I deploy it out to my azure app service any functions using the Authorize(Role = tag will keep directing me back to my login. After logging in I have checked for current roles users are assigned to and it does display the proper roles but the authorizes roles tag will not work as it should and redirect me to the proper page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can refer to [Add authorization using app roles & roles claims to an ASP.NET Core web app that's signs-in users with the Microsoft identity platform](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles)